# I would like to call a function in node(serve end) from my front end JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am a beginner so some of my words might not be very accurate(I have been told) but I have tried to be as clear as possible in explaining my question.

On my client side the function below is called when I click a button on the browser. I would like to send the data in the variables `hellojson`, `Build` and `newinputB` to a function in node.

```
function saved_dem(){
  const hellojson = "finn.json";
  const Build = "Inventory";
  const newinputB = "20000";
  console.log("Am here");
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(this.readyState,this.status)
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log("Succesfully done");
        console.log(this.responseText);
        // I would like to call my function in node js somewhere here am not sure if this is right
    }
  request.open("GET","http://localhost:3000",true);
  request.send("here");
  }
}
```

On my server side this what I have so far.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  const rev = `Request received`
  console.log(req)
   //calling my intended function here
  opethefile(hellojson,Build,newinputB)
  res.send(rev)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))


//the target function I want to call
function opethefile(hellojson,Build,newinputB){
  console.log("Function called")
}
```

I have been on this project for days close to a week. I have tried using so many different examples online but none was actually close to my problem or it was explained in way I couldn't understand. I can't seem to get this together to work.
Your help will be immensely appreciated!!.

Comment: Not sure if using  `fetch` or `XMLH` would make a difference. Nothing is actually happening it just opens and prints on the web browser `Request received` nothing else happens that I have noticed

Answer (score 0):

To send data to your backend you can use XHR POST method:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;                                
const url = 'https://api-to-call.com/endpoint';
const dataToSend = {
  hellojson: 'finn.json', 
  Build: 'Inventory', 
  newinputB: '20000'
};
const data = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);                    // converts data to a string

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    return xhr.response;
  }
}
xhr.open('POST', url);      // opens request
xhr.send(data);         // sends object
```

If you are using a express version lower than 4.16, to access your request data in the backend, you have to use body parser:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

Comment: Just some quiz questions please if you don't mind, form your code why did use the line `const url = 'https://api-to-call.com/endpoint';` since am not connecting to any api and I just need to access the node file. Could you clarify this part for me ?  And where do I call my function as that was the main question ? Thanks.

Comment: @JampiuAtila .. `const url = 'https://api-to-call.com/endpoint';` this is basically where you are making the API to. In your case, it'll be `const url = 'http://localhost:3000';` It is always a good practice to declare values like this is variables.

Comment: I am getting this error : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Updatar.js:101 POST http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_FAILED` . How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are beginner, here are very simple solution for you to learn,

**client side changes:**

You must put 2 lines that is `request.open("GET","http://localhost:3000",true);` and `request.send("here");` outside `onreadystatechange` function/listener

so complete client side code

```
function saved_dem(){
  const hellojson = "finn.json";
  const Build = "Inventory";
  const newinputB = "20000";
  console.log("Am here");
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(this.readyState,this.status)
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log("Succesfully done");
        console.log(this.responseText);
        // I would like to call my function in node js somewhere here am not sure if this is right
    }
  }
  request.open("GET","http://localhost:3000?hellojson=" + hellojson + "&Build=" + Build + "&newinputB=" +newinputB);
  request.send();
}
```

**Server side changes:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  const rev = `Request received`
  console.log(req.query);
   //calling my intended function here
  opethefile(req.query.hellojson, req.query.Build, req.query.newinputB)
  res.send(rev)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))


//the target function I want to call
function opethefile(hellojson, Build, newinputB){
  console.log("Function called", hellojson, Build, newinputB);
}
```

---

**Here are another better solution using POST http method and JSON data:**

---

**client side code:**

```
function saved_dem(){
  const hellojson = "finn.json";
  const Build = "Inventory";
  const newinputB = "20000";
  console.log("Am here");
  const data = JSON.stringify({hellojson, Build, newinputB});
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(this.readyState,this.status)
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log("Succesfully done");
        console.log(this.responseText);
        // I would like to call my function in node js somewhere here am not sure if this is right
    }
  }
  request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000");
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.send(data);
}
```

**Server side code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

// middleware to parse json body data
app.use(express.json());


app.post('/', (req, res) =>{
  const rev = `Request received`
  console.log(req.body);
   //calling my intended function here
  opethefile(req.body.hellojson, req.body.Build, req.body.newinputB)
  res.send(rev)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))


//the target function I want to call
function opethefile(hellojson, Build, newinputB){
  console.log("Function called", hellojson, Build, newinputB);
}
```

**Server side with whitelist all domain**

first install it from command line or terminal

```
npm install cors
```

and then use cors module as middleware

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


app.post('/', (req, res) =>{
  const rev = `Request received`
  console.log(req.body);
   //calling my intended function here
  opethefile(req.body.hellojson, req.body.Build, req.body.newinputB)
  res.send(rev)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))


//the target function I want to call
function opethefile(hellojson, Build, newinputB){
  console.log("Function called", hellojson, Build, newinputB);
}
```

Comment: the first solution you gave gives me an error of `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/?hellojson=finn.json&Build=Inventory&newinputB=20000' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and `Updatar.js:99 GET http://localhost:3000/?hellojson=finn.json&Build=Inventory&newinputB=20000 net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: The second solution also gives the same error

Comment: @JampiuAtila You need to handle `CORS` in server side, you may use https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html to fix CORS issue.
So first you need to install cors module in server side `npm install cors` and include it like `const cors = require('cors');` and then use it as middleware `app.use(cors());`